# MySQL вопрос по хранению данных

Tags: mysql

База данных содержит информацию про фильм:

```
ID(int)
FilmDuration(string)
Year(int)
Description(string)
ID_Of_Folder(int)
```

Каждый фильм имеет жанр, но фильм может быть одновременно и боевиком, и комедией,  и драмой. Как в таком случае хранить эту информацию?
У меня два варинта, какой из них более предпочтительный?

**Вариант 1:**
Создать такую таблицу:

```
ID_of_film(INT) reference
Боевик(bool)
Комедия(bool)
Драма(bool)
Ужасы(bool)
...
```

**Вариант 2:**
Для каждого жанра создать свою таблицу, которая будет хранить лишь одно значение - внешний ключ, который будет указывать на ID фильма.

```
Боевик
---------------------
| ID(int) reference |
---------------------

Комедия
----------------------
| ID(int) reference  |
----------------------
```

Или все же есть лучший подход к хранению такой информации?

Comment: я бы создал 3 таблицы - фильмы, жанры и фильм/жанр (id фильма, id жанра). затем в будущем не будет проблем с добавлением новых жанров или перечислением всех таблиц в запросах

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis Тоесть, например, если фильм под ID 10 имеет 3 жанра, то соотвествено в таблице фильм/жанр будет 3 записи, я правильно вас понимаю?

Comment: да, именно так.

Comment: Именно так. Впрочем, если вы абсолютно уверены, что новых жанров у вас не будет, то вы скорее всего ошибаетесь ;), но если всё же нет — первый, как по мне, чуток быстрее.

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis Благодарен за ответ. Думаю, этот вариат найболее рационален и предпочтителен.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Требуется использовать связь многие-ко-многим. У одного фильма может быть множество жанров, у одного жанра может быть множество фильмов. Для этого используется pivot таблица, по которой можно получить связь фильмов и жанров.

Пример таблиц:

films table:

```
ID(int)
FilmDuration(string)
Year(int)
Description(string)
ID_Of_Folder(int)
```

genres(жанры) table:

```
ID(int)
TITLE(string) - название жанра (Боевик/Драма/Комедия)
```

film_genre table

```
FILM_ID(int) - id фильма
GENRE_ID(int) - id жанра
```